# SQL Query Converting select-from-join to LinQ

Tags: sql-server, linq

I'm working on 'NorthWind' database and I want to convert my SQL codes to LinQ.

Here my codes:

```
select s.CompanyName,o.OrderID, o.Freight 
from Orders as o 
join Shippers as s on o.ShipVia = s.ShipperID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = from o in db.Orders
            join s in db.Shippers on o.ShipVia equals s.ShipperID
            select new {
               o.OrderID,
               o.Freight,
               s.CompanyName
            };
```

I suggest you to use [LINQ Pad](http://www.linqpad.net/) for learning LINQ and testing your queries.